# append json key value pair to a .json file Titanium

Tags: javascript, json, titanium, appcelerator

I have a .json file named wordsAndMeaning.json

```
{
    "words" : [
        {   
            "name" : "Apple",
            "meaning" : "A fruit"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Truck",
            "meaning" : "A heavy vehicle"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Zebra",
            "meaning" : "An animal"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Rock",
            "meaning" : "A music Genre"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have two textfields in my window that takes the name and the meaning of the name and a submit button.

What I want to do is after I fill in the textFields and click on Submit(i.e addEventListener), i want the entered data to be appended as new key-value pair to the above wordsAndMeanings.json file.

wordsandMeanings.json file exists in the resourcesDirectory, and I am using fileSystem to implement this.

I am new to JSON concept. so detailed explanation with code will be appreciated. I am implementing this task in Titanium.

I'll put my entire app.js code below

```
var window = Ti.UI.createWindow();

var view1 = Titanium.UI.createView({
    backgroundcolor:'21DCEE'
});
var view2 = Titanium.UI.createView({});

var textName = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
    top:100,
    left:50,
    height:50,
    width:150,
    borderStyle: Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
    hintText:'Enter the word'
});

var textMeaning = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
    top: 200,
    left:50,
    width:150,
    height:50,
    borderStyle: Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
    hintText:'Enter its meaning'
});

var submit = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    top:300,
    left:100,
    title:'Submit'
});

var tableView = Ti.UI.createTableView();
var tableData = [];
var fileName = 'wordsAndMeanings.json';
var file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory, fileName); 
var preParseData = file.read();
var response = JSON.parse(preParseData);
Ti.API.info(response.words.length);
for(var i = 0; i < response.words.length ; i++){
    word = response.words[i];
    row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
        height : '60dp'
    });
    nameLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text: word.name,
        font: { fontSize:'24dp', fontWeight:'bold'},
        height:'auto',
        left:'10dp',
        color:'#000',
        touchEnabled : false
    });
    row.add(nameLabel);
    tableData.push(row);
    tableView.setData(tableData);
}

var add = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title: 'Add',
    top: 150,
    left: 50
});

add.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    window2 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
        backgroundColor:'8FD2ED'
    });

    submit.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        //response.words.push({"name" : "abc", "meaning" : "alphabets"});
        //Ti.API.info(typeof(textName.value));
        //var one = JSON.parse(textName.value);
        //Ti.API.info(one);
        var obj = eval("(textName.value)");
        Ti.API.info(obj);
        //var file2 = Titanium.FileSystem.getFile(Titanium.FileSystem.resourcesDirectory,'wordsAndMeanings.json');
        //file2.write()
    });


    window2.open();
    window2.add(view2);
    view2.add(textName);
    view2.add(textMeaning);
    view2.add(submit);
});
window.open();
window.add(view1);
view1.add(tableView);
view1.add(add);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the docs @Anand linked to, you'll see that you cannot write in the resourcesDirectory. You can save your new file in the applicationDataDirectory, and load from that file afterward.

Since you are already parsing your data in a dictionary (`var response = JSON.parse(preParseData);`), I would append your new data exactly the way you have done it in the submit eventListener (`//response.words.push({"name" : "abc", "meaning" : "alphabets"});`), and at the end, [stringify](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Global.JSON) the response dictionary to save it.

1) So read and parse the json:

```
var fileName = 'wordsAndMeanings.json';
var file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory, fileName); 
var preParseData = file.read().text; // file.read() will return the blob. file.read().text is what you want
var response = JSON.parse(preParseData);
```

2) Get fields data on submit click and append data

```
submit.addEventListener(click, function(e) {
 var userTextMeaning = textMeaning.value; // Read value property of both fields
 var userTextName = textName.value;
 response.words.push({"name" : userTextName, "meaning" : userTextMeaning}); // Push the new data to response list
}
```

3) Stringify and save in applicationDataDirectory

```
var fileName = 'wordsAndMeanings.json';
var file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, fileName); 
var json = JSON.stringify(response);
file.write(json)
```

Comment: As per [link] (https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Filesystem+Access+and+Storage) resourcesDirectory supports read and write on a SIMULATOR/EMULATOR. I am working on the simulator, not on a actual device.

And also I need to write the **text field** data (i.e textName and textMeaning) into the .json file, how do I extract that data and write it to the file as new key-value pair?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [write method](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Filesystem.File-method-write) to write to a file in Titanium. You should understand about [Titanium File System](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.Filesystem) before doing this.

Also you should change the statement `var obj = eval("(textName.value)");` to `var obj = eval("(" + textName.value + ")");`.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Titanium.App.Properties()`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App.Properties) instead of file system would be much better. You can easily store and retrieve whole object using:

- `Ti.App.Properties.getObject('propertyName', defaultValue);` - Second parameter is returned when property doesn't exist.
- `Ti.App.Properties.setObject('propertyName', value);`